# ffmpeg muxing 6 mono wavs and prores mov into new 6 channel mov - how to?

Tags: ffmpeg

i've been dealing with this for a day now and finally have to just come out and ask. i want to take a prores mov file that is silent (but apparently does have a timecode track) and losslessly mux it with 6 mono wav files, having the 6 mono wavs become 6 uncompressed channels (not 6 streams) in the final mov.

how do i do this?

the attempts i've made have all failed in some way or other. either i get a conflict where a filter is employed which prevents a direct copy, or i get an error in mapping, or something else. i've seen lots on working with either a single audio channel and picture but nothing on muxing 5.1 with picture. either that or there is transcoding being done but not straight copying. also found a lot on extracting but nothing much on combining.

here's the last command i tried, which gave me an aac audio track with the correct number of channels but, obviously, was not just a copy of the uncompressed wavs:

ffmpeg -i pix.mov -i L.wav -i R .wav -i C.wav -i LFE.wav -i Ls.wav -i Rs.wav -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a]amerge=inputs=6[aout]" -map "[aout]" -c:v copy -c:a copy muxed51.mov

this threw the error that -filter_complex is incompatible with -c:a copy, which makes sense now that i've seen it. without the -c:a copy switch i got an mp4 mov with no picture and aac audio. i think i tried it also with the -filter_complex parameters running from 0-5 rather than the 1-6 as they are here. i think i was trying to leave room for the video stream to copy into the 0 space. obviously not a coder here. i just need to get this done and it seemed like it should be pretty simple. not turning out that way.

to sum up, how do i just copy the video and 6 mono wavs into a mov container with the audio as 6 channels? both picture and audio should be lossless copies.

thanks,
BabaG

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i pix.mov -i L.wav -i R .wav -i C.wav -i LFE.wav -i Ls.wav -i Rs.wav 
 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a]amerge=inputs=6[aout]"
 -map "[aout]" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le muxed51.mov
```

Merging or splitting channels can't be done in copy mode. But you don't have to use a lossy codec like AAC. PCM will be a lossless transcode, provided your source files have depth 16 bit.

Comment: thanks, Mulvya. very helpful. before i got your response i actually found something that also worked. same as your posting but i had -map 0:0 before the -c:v. i guess that's not needed. i also used pcm_s24le as the source is 24 bit.

Comment: i do have another question. i'm seeing that different apps seem to interpret the channel order of the resultant file in different ways. i'm wondering if i can 'bake in' something that will tell all apps the order of the channels. how can i embed channel order info into the output file?  thanks, BabaG